# Using variable being initialized in a designated initializer

Tags: c, designated-initializer

Am I allowed to use a variable being initialized inside a designated initializer?

Consider the following listing:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    int * const a_ptr;
};

struct A foo(int a) {
    struct A result = {
        .a = a,
        .a_ptr = &result.a
    };

    return result;
}
```

<kbd>[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tseh6qj8K)</kbd>

Am I allowed to use `result` in this designated initializer expression? Is this behavior defined? Is this code portable?

*Update*

My bad, the example contains a potential stack corruption. The listing should be:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    int * const a_ptr;
};

void foo(int a) {
    struct A result = {
        .a = a,
        .a_ptr = &result.a
    };

    bar(&result);
}
```

Comment: Beware that once *value* of `result` is returned, `a_ptr` will be a pointer to deallocated stack memory

Comment: Not any different than `void *p = &p;` and I believe there is a duplicate for that somewhere.

Comment: @user16217248, you're right, I shouldn't be returning this struct. It's just for illustration purposes.

Comment: @ivaigult your question remains a bit unclear, there are two very different code snippets, so which one are you actually asking about?

Comment: @Jabberwocky the later one. I kept the old version just to be nice with people posted the first comments on this, so I don't invalidate their comments. The question is solely about the syntax construction and the order of initialization, it's not about the UB I introduced in the first version.

Comment: It depends which C version you are using; C90 will not allow it, but also doesn't have designated initializers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization by itself is fine.

At the time `result` is declared, its address (as well as the addresses of its fields) is constant.  So it is safe to use `&result.a` in the initializer of `result`.

What *is* a problem however is that you're returning a copy of this structure.  This copy contains the address of a local variable that no longer exists, so attempting to use the value of the `a_ptr` member of the returned struct will trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: But is it OK to use the value of a previously initialized field? `struct {int a, b;} myStruct = {.a - 10, .b = a};`

Comment: @user16217248 I don't think the order of initialization is well-defined.

Comment: @user16217248 That's a different case.  The order of initialization is unspecified, so there's no guarantee that `.a` will be set before `.b`.

Comment: @dbush I think it's not quite true. The order is [defined](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) in 6.7.9 paragraph 11. 

"In contrast, a designation causes  the  following  initializer  to  begin  initialization  of  the  subobject described  by  the  designator. Initialization  then  continues  forward  in  order,  beginning with the next subobject after that described by the designator."

Comment: @ivaigult That clause is telling you which subobjects an initializer is associated with, not evaluation order.  p23 talks about evaluation: *"The  evaluations  of  the  initialization  list  expressions  are  indeterminately  sequenced  with respect to one another and thus the order in which any side effects occur is unspecified."*

Answer (score 1):

The question has changed completely, here is my new answer:

Your code is fine, you can check this, it won't assert on any platform.

You pass the pointer to the local variable `result` to `bar`. In `bar` that local variable still exists `p` points to that variable (result). Therefore the `a_ptr` still points to `result.a`.

But I'm just wondering what you're trying to achieve here.

```
#include <assert.h>

struct A {
  int a;
  int* const a_ptr;
};    

void bar(struct A *p)
{
  assert(p->a_ptr == &p->a);
}    

void foo(int a) {
  struct A result = {
      .a = a,
      .a_ptr = &result.a
  };

  bar(&result);
}

int main()
{
  foo(2);
}
```

BTW:

```
 struct A result = {
      .a = a,
      .a_ptr = &result.a
  };
```

is equivalent to this:

```
  struct A result;  
  result.a = a;
  result.a_ptr = &result.a;
```

but for latter you'd need to declare `int* a_ptr;` instead of `int* const a_ptr;`.